# Undefined variables error

Tags: theming

I was working on transferring my website to a new folder. Same database, just a new folder. Worked a bit on the new address, etc.

When I went back to the old address, website is not working anymore. More precisely, it throws a lot of "undefined variables" alerts that clearly have to do with the theme, but I'm pretty sure I have not touched any files there...

```
Notice: Undefined variable: site_logo in include() (line 16 of /hsphere/local/home/ulufenci/test.ulufencing.net/sites/all/themes/corolla/templates/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: site_logo in include() (line 18 of /hsphere/local/home/ulufenci/test.ulufencing.net/sites/all/themes/corolla/templates/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: site_logo in include() (line 21 of /hsphere/local/home/ulufenci/test.ulufencing.net/sites/all/themes/corolla/templates/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: hgroup_attributes in include() (line 28 of /hsphere/local/home/ulufenci/test.ulufencing.net/sites/all/themes/corolla/templates/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: site_name_attributes in include() (line 31 of /hsphere/local/home/ulufenci/test.ulufencing.net/sites/all/themes/corolla/templates/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: tag in include() (line 100 of /hsphere/local/home/ulufenci/test.ulufencing.net/sites/all/themes/corolla/templates/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: primary_local_tasks in include() (line 102 of /hsphere/local/home/ulufenci/test.ulufencing.net/sites/all/themes/corolla/templates/page.tpl.php).
Notice: Undefined variable: secondary_local_tasks in include() (line 117 of /hsphere/local/home/ulufenci/test.ulufencing.net/sites/all/themes/corolla/templates/page.tpl.php).
```

are the kind of errors that I get. I'm using the theme Corolla. Can you please provide any lead as to what might be causing the error?

Thank you!!!

Comment: Have you cleared the cache and navigated to the theme settings page and re-saved the theme settings?

Comment: Thank you Patrick, I unfortunately cannot access the admin pages anymore because of the bug. Is there a way to do that through the database?

Comment: You can clear the cache through Drush if you have that set up...

Comment: Unfortunately I don't... :/

Comment: I once have cleared caches in simmilar situation by truncating tables in database with cache_ prefix but please do reasearch before doing it, it is extremely dangerous ! Trying to setup Drush is more safer way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to clear the cache by emptying all the _cache tables in the database. I then navigated to the theme (Corolla) settings page and clicked on save settings.

And gone. All errors now seem gone.

Thank you very much Patrick K, I wish I could vote your suggestion up! (Will do if you repost it as an answer rather than a comment.) 
Cheers!